# Kolab groupware(Mail Server) fails to install because of dependency problems

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I need some help. I'm trying to setup a kolab sever to be used by computer science students at my college, starting this fall. I had a bit of some trouble setting up ldap, bur after some experimenting it finally worked. Now I'm having trouble installing kolab.

IN SUMMARY:

```
sudo apt-get install kolab

(...)

dpkg: error processing kolab-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kolab-server:
 kolab-server depends on pykolab (= 0.5.11-5); however:
  Package pykolab is not configured yet.

(...)

dpkg: error processing kolab-saslauthd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pykolab
 kolab-cli
 kolab-server
 kolab-conf
 wallace
 kolab
 kolab-xml
 kolab-mta
 kolab-saslauthd
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow instalation instructions from here

http://docs.kolab.org/en-US/Kolab_Groupware/3.0/html/Community_Installation_Guide/index.html

because few people over there are saying they can't get working kolbag v. 2.x on ubuntu, but kolab 3.x is working

https://kolab.org/blog/henning-holly/2013/04/28/kolab-3-collaboration-server-ubuntu

and! ubntu is not a priority for them, you can try to use openSUSE as server, I guess..

Comment: well, this is your point of view, anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's more than 10 days that I'm working on installing Kolab on ubuntu, but with no success.
I used the [guide](http://docs.kolab.org/en-US/Kolab_Groupware/3.0/html/Community_Installation_Guide/index.html) on its site, but it's not working at all.
I did the following works:

1. Adding the following addresses to sources.list

   - deb http://mirror.kolabsys.com/pub/ubuntu/kolab-3.0/ precise release updates
   - deb-src http://mirror.kolabsys.com/pub/ubuntu/kolab-3.0/ precise release updates
2. After that, I make preferences at `/etc/apt/preferences` and add the following lines to it:
   `Package: *
   Pin: origin mirror.kolabsys.com
   Pin-Priority: 501`
3. Then update the repository `sudo apt-get update`. Everythings up to here going true.
4. The problems appear here, when installing the Kolab, `sudo apt-get install kolab`.
   The errors are exactly like your ones.
5. For a solution I installed aptitude, `sudo apt-get aptitude`.
6. Then run the following command: `sudo aptitude install kolab`. The following lines appear in terminal:

   [image] 

   that I accepted it by entering `Y` and everythings going to install.
7. Finally, after some moments everythings installed, but according the chapter 4 of guide for running `setup-kolab`, it prompt me that `command not found`. 

    [image]

I don't know what to do, That's all of my experiences.

Comment: Finally by the above solution I installed it on Debian 7.01, But again and again trying on Ubuntu 12.04 is failed.